# Drawbacks of Yammer Authentication with HttpWebRequest

Tags: yammer

I'm working on a migration product that migrates data in to Yammer and I use the Yammer REST API. I perform programmatic Yammer authentication using HttpWebRequest as posted here - [Yammer Authentication with HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389113/yammer-authentication-with-httpwebrequest) . I'm thinking that if Yammer changes the internals of its authentication (such as changing the number of cookies that gets sent back and forth) I might run in to an issue. Has anyone used this approach and would recommend it ?

Answer (score 0):

Not supported - see other SO thread on this here:

[Yammer Authentication with HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389113/yammer-authentication-with-httpwebrequest)

And Microsoft Technet article here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2013/10/05/using-the-yammer-api-in-a-net-client-application.aspx

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow what you are trying to say here. Not Supported meaning Yammer does not support it and you do NOT recommended it ? I'm using the approach as suggested in http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2013/10/05/using-the-yammer-api-in-a-net-client-application.aspx                         and I posted the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389113/yammer-authentication-with-httpwebrequest