# Yammer Authentication issue

Tags: yammer

Since Yammer has enabled SSO with office 365, yammer authentication with httpwebrequest as suggested here - [Yammer authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389113/yammer-authentication-with-httpwebrequest)   does not work anymore. How to overcome this ?