# Connecting to Yammer from Azure Webjob

Tags: c#, yammer, azure-webjobs

I am attempting to connect to Yammer using their .NET SDK but I am having a hell of a time managing this... The point of this exercise is to create an application in Azure which periodically - and AUTONOMOUSLY - contacts Yammer and fetches the latest messages from a specific Yammer group.

Does anyone know of the correct way to use the Yammer .NET SDK from, let's say, a console application, which does not rely on a browser (a.k.a. direct user interaction) to successfully connect via OAuth authentication?

---

**What I have tried**:

Trying to suss out what to do from the example given on [.NET SDK page on developer.yammer.com](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/net-sdk), you can see under "Standard Process" an example which shows the `LaunchSignIn()` function with an incorrect signature! The example shows the usage as:

```
var authResponse = await OAuthUtils.LaunchSignIn(_clientConfig.ClientId, _clientConfig.RedirectUri, ssoEnabled);
```

whereas the actually signature I get from the dll is:

```
void OAuthUtils.LaunchSignIn(string clientId, string RedirectUri)
```

I'll forgive the missing `ssoEnabled` parameter... but the example claims the function receives a response, from which a `Code` is then extracted. This is, of course, the piece missing from my attempt to call:

```
(awaitable) Task<AuthEnvelope> AuthClient.AuthenticateAppAsync(string code)
```

I have scoured Google for information on the use of the Yammer .NET SDK but have come up empty handed. All manner of examples of connecting to Yammer but none are in any way relevant to the .NET API. The only thing in any way relevant that I have seen is the [Yammer .NET API example uploaded](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/blog/announcing-the-yammer-net-sdk-1), apparently, by the person who developed it, [who posted the code on GitHub](https://github.com/yammer/dotnet-yammersdk). I have checked this example but the two parts in it - one for Windows Phone and one for Windows "Modern App" - both rely on a Browser object being available, or something to that effect anyway. There are redirects, I'm supposed to have a RedirectUri for Yammer to direct me... [So does this other example](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/using-the-yammer-api-in-a-net-client-application/) - which was the ONLY other example of using the .NET SDK that I could find.

I imagine that the reason the signature is different is because this isn't actually the same function at all. The one I am trying to use is in `Yammer.Oss.Api.Utils` whereas the example application doesn't even have the letters `Utils` together other than in the name of the class `OAuthUtils`... which leads me to believe that it is possibly under `Yammer.Oss.Core.WinRT` which, as luck would have it, I cannot reference at all... `Yammer.Oss.Core` only contains `Collections`, `Constants`, `Extensions` and `Serialization`.

By the way, in the announcement of the .NET SDK (see first link above), the link to documentation for the SDK leads to the Yammer Support page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the .NET SDK and just do the authorization yourself using the [server-side flow](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/oauth-2). Then make the requests with [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) and [add the Authorization header](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/api-requests). The SDK might be helpful with some Modern Apps but it's overkill for most people. When working with the API manually the worst thing you'll have to deal with is deserializing the JSON responses with JSON.NET, or other JSON library.

You don't say what you are trying to build, but AFAIK WebJobs don't have a UI so you'll need to do the authorization from a console app or website. Then store the resulting OAuth token somewhere that the WebJob can access it. If you have need an OAuth token per user you'll need to store those in a database, but make efforts to protect them because each OAuth token provides access to their Yammer account.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer as it satisfactorily answers the question regarding .NET SDK, though it did not yet help me advance much in terms of actually connecting to Yammer. All calls past the initial call to Yammer in the authentication processes return a 404...

Comment: It seems I was getting a 404 because I wasn't supplying Yammer with the cookies it required with the request as shown here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389113/yammer-authentication-with-httpwebrequest. Seems to be running now. Will check it on Azure WebJob